# Can anyone tell me why there is space of the <body> between my divs?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I am new to coding and stuff and I am wondering why there is a space of the body in between the divs in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkhr5e7w/6/)?

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
  <!-- body -->
<body>
  <div class="top-navbar navbar" id="color-1">
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="art.html">Art</a>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="sgrumble.png" alt="sg-rumble" class="front-image">
  </div>

  <div class="top-bar-2 navbar" id="color-1">
    <a href="#project">Project</a>
    <a href="#divname">Champions</a>
    <a href="#divname2">divname2</a>
    <a href="#divname3">divname3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="about-text" id="color-1">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <p>short info text about text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="collection art" id="project color-2">
    <h3>text</h3>
    <p>text.</p>

    <div class="project-blue">
      <img src="/asset/images/project-ashe256x256.png" class="project-ashe">
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
#color-1 {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
#color-2 {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.top-navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.top-navbar a {
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.top-navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #8a8a8a;
}
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 491px;
    background-color: red;
}
.top-bar-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.top-bar-2 a {
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.top-bar-2 a:hover {
    background-color: #8a8a8a;
}
.collection {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue
```

The green part which is the body is showing in between the second navbar and the two text divs. Anyone know whats wrong cause I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

The h4 and the p elements have a margin set. You can see that using the "inspect" option right clicking the element in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

its good to use:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

this will remove every space in your document.

note: in html, document itself have default space. so by above CSS you can remove them easily.

it is a good practice to use above CSS in your every stylesheet files.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have not [reset the default](https://medium.com/@tinydinosaur/a-wordy-history-of-default-browser-styles-and-css-resets-befdd614d93b) margins of header elements.

Reset defaults using

```
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

At the top of your sheet.

```css
  * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

#color-1 {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

#color-2 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.top-navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.top-navbar a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #8a8a8a;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 491px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top-bar-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-bar-2 a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-bar-2 a:hover {
  background-color: #8a8a8a;
}

.collection {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<!-- body -->

<body>
  <div class="top-navbar navbar" id="color-1">
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="art.html">Art</a>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="sgrumble.png" alt="sg-rumble" class="front-image">
  </div>

  <div class="top-bar-2 navbar" id="color-1">
    <a href="#project">Project</a>
    <a href="#divname">Champions</a>
    <a href="#divname2">divname2</a>
    <a href="#divname3">divname3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="about-text" id="color-1">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <p>short info text about text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="collection art" id="project color-2">
    <h3>text</h3>
    <p>text.</p>

    <div class="project-blue">
      <img src="/asset/images/project-ashe256x256.png" class="project-ashe">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Green is body color. Where is no element with background-color there is body color because nothing is overlapping it.

CSS boxmodel will be helpfull: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

**Margin property is external part of an element.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```css
h3,h4,p{
  margin:0;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
#color-1 {
 background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
#color-2 {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.top-navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}
.top-navbar a {
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-navbar a:hover {
 background-color: #8a8a8a;
}
.image {
 width: 100%;
 height: 491px;
 background-color: red;
}
.top-bar-2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}
.top-bar-2 a {
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-bar-2 a:hover {
 background-color: #8a8a8a;
}
.collection {
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
  <!-- body -->
<body>
  <div class="top-navbar navbar" id="color-1">
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="art.html">Art</a>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image">
    <img src="sgrumble.png" alt="sg-rumble" class="front-image">
  </div>
  
  <div class="top-bar-2 navbar" id="color-1">
    <a href="#project">Project</a>
 <a href="#divname">Champions</a>
 <a href="#divname2">divname2</a>
 <a href="#divname3">divname3</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="about-text" id="color-1">
 <h4>title</h4>
 <p>short info text about text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="collection art" id="project color-2">
    <h3>text</h3>
 <p>text.</p>
 
 <div class="project-blue">
   <img src="/asset/images/project-ashe256x256.png" class="project-ashe">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify (add to existing) the following css and the spaces will be removed.

```
.about-text {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collection {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```